# Present view controller modally over current context programmatically using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using following code to present a view controller modally. I have changed presentation style to "Over current Context". It works fine on iOS 8 but screen gets black on os < 8. I know Over Current Context is available only in iOS 8. My question is how can I achieve this in iOS 7.

```
let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("markerView") as! MarkerViewController
```

`self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to use `Current Context` for iOS 7.

To check the iOS-Version you can use `NSFoundationVersionNumber`.

```
let iOS7 = floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
let iOS8 = floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
```

Then you can check which version is running and use `OverCurrentContext` or `CurrentContext`.

```
if iOS8 {
  self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
} else {
  self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me. Still on iOS 7 screen is black.

Comment: In iOS7 you have to set the presentation style on the presenter.

Also those iOS checks seem questionable in general, a update say to 7.2 would break both cases.

Comment: In tab bar controller .overCurrentContext doesn't cover tab bar. .overFullScreen resolves this.